# How to find an object allocated code in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

see an example below

```
var a = {name:'example'};
var b = a;
var c = b;
```

Here `c` and `b` and `a` are the same object, they are just references of `a`.
My problem is, I am debugging a very large program, e.g. I am at **line 3**, and I know `c` is an object valued `{name:'example'}`, but I want to know where this object was allocated the very first time. In this example, **line 1** is the answer.

So, could Chrome DevTools make it?

p.s. `console.trace()` may have some help, but the existing program was too complex and trace was not deep enough for debugging.

Comment: Maybe devtools - Memory - Snapshot, then find by text and inspect the retainers sub-panel?